# My battery won't charge when plugged in (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, laptop, battery

I plugged in and turned on my laptop (Asus) which has Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it. It has been working fine up until now and now the battery is not charging when plugged in and the charge is going down (as it would if not plugged in).
I have not dropped my laptop or the plug and the only thing I can think of is that this is a software thing but I have run 'sudo apt update && apt upgrade' which told me everything was fine and nothing needed updating/upgrading. I have tried going back to a previous kernal but that didn't fix it. I am at a loss as to what to do and feel that the only thing I can do is reinstall Ubuntu. It was fine yesterday and did an update so maybe that is it and there was something wrong with that.

What should I do?

Comment: The AC power adapter is bad, or unplugged, or some other hardware problem, or the Power Manager may need to be reset. Is your battery user-removable?

Comment: I ran a live USB of Ubuntu 18.04 and 'tried Ubuntu without installing' which worked and showed the battery charging so it is definitely a software issue.

Comment: You didn't say if you have a removable battery.

Comment: sorry, the battery is not removable. I wish it was but that's the way laptop design is going apperantly (or so I was told:-/ ).

Comment: Although this isn't the correct way to reset the Power Manager, let's try it anyway... turn off the laptop, press and HOLD the power button for 15 seconds, even if the laptop turns on. Recheck the charging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly I am stupid and have asked this question twice but managed to solve it this time by following this solution here:

https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/new-asus-laptop-plugged-in-not-charging-630258/

I'm very sorry for wasting anyone's time. It seems I wasn't patient enough.

Comment: Link is dead. Please post the solution text in the future. 
1) Disconnected the power 
2) Held the power button down for approximately 15 seconds
3) Reconnected the power (noticed the charge light was no longer blinking!)
4) Powered up.......battery/power icon reading "13% available (plugged in, CHARGING!)" https://web.archive.org/web/20201206174028/https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/new-asus-laptop-plugged-in-not-charging-630258/ Doesn't work for me though.

Comment: @TiHausmann: Sorry, I had forgotten I had posted this question and hadn't thought to post the solution from the link either. Thanks for the heads up and I will post solutions not just links in future.

Comment: Doesn't work on Thinkpad X230 / Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Barra : You can still edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just restart a few times a day or do a reinstall of Ubuntu. One day I had a problem similar like this, A reinstall solved it.

Comment: I'll try a restart every so often so. I can't stay on long as once the battery which isn't removable (blame the new way laptops are now) goes I have no way of getting back in. I'll keep coming back to see if there's an update that'll fix it. If not, I think I will need to reinstall, like you said.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but the Ubuntu 20.04 release seems to fix that for me.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think it was a software problem. I've no idea what exactly or why it caused this but I solved the problem when I realised I had 'Timeshift' installed and 'rolled back' Ubuntu to 8 days or so ago which seems to have solved the problem:)

Thank you all for all your answers and kind advice and I'd just advise anybody else to install 'Timeshift' as it was an absolute wonder and fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well after Ubuntu installation, fixed it with the power button trick. Often when there is some kind of a problem with these HW related things, especially battery, this works since this method resets some internal settings and forces the whole machine to get rid of some problematic voltage here and there (turns it COMPLETELY off).

Make sure to search for the recommended approach by the laptop manufacturer. Look for "How to power reset the ... laptop" or something like this.
The most generic approach is to turn off the machine, pull out the battery and hold the power button for one minute (usually less but to make sure we cover all models). When the battery is not detachable (you cannot pull it off without actually dissecting the machine with screwdrivers etc.) skip this step and hold the power button when the machine is off.

No need to be scared, this reset should not mess with BIOS settings, booting or the installed systems.

Other similar advice [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/12nyre/30_second_power_button_trick/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/qa53vb/laptop_is_stuck_on_restarting_and_holding_the/), [here](https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2018/11/06/how-to-power-reset-your-laptop-computer) or [here](https://bleuwire.com/how-to-power-reset-your-laptop-computer/).