# Laptop not charging in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

My laptop charges fine in windows but I had been facing issues with charging it in ubuntu. I was using ubuntu 18.04 until yesterday, facing the not charging problem. I decided to upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 hoping the issue will get fixed. When I updated, it did start charging once, but when I started the laptop after a few hours, it stopped charging again.

The battery indicator just keeps showing "Estimating...".

I ran across this one command on internet I really don't know what it does but seems it might be useful for someone who answers this:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

The output for this is:

[image]

Running: `acpi` gives output : Battery 0: Unknown, 16%

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This may be totally unrelated but on my thinkpad x240 with 19.10 I am finding it only starts showing as charging around 15 minutes after I plug it in. It shows discharging for those 15 mins or so. Also I wonder if it's related to model/manufacturer - it won't harm to disclose what machine you're on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My battery won't charge when plugged in (Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209033/my-battery-wont-charge-when-plugged-in-ubuntu-18-04)