# HP Zbook 15 G2 battery not charging with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: hp, battery, 22.04

On my HP Zbook 15 G2 I've switched from windows to Ubuntu 22.04. This works except that the battery is no longer charging. It's stuck at 0% with the charging symbol on, stating it's "estimating".

[image: Battery is charging]

If I type the command:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

I get:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                Primary
  serial:               59099 2015/06/06
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              di 24 mei 2022 13:10:33 CEST (11 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         43,0992 Wh
    energy-full-design:  43,0992 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             13,984 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

If I unplug the charger it immediately shuts down the laptop.

I've tried installing Ubuntu 18.04, but that resulted in the same issue.

I've googled a bit but only found windows specific solutions.

Comment: Is it the same issue when you boot from the `live  USB` or `live CD` ?

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 I've only tried it with the `live USB` and I had the same issue

Comment: You can try to update the bios/uefi of your system from windows, more information: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_4123786-2338478-16

Comment: does it charge when it's off?

Comment: @Esther it does not unfortunately

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 I didn't make it dual boot, I just installed Ubuntu only, so I cannot really do anything from windows I think?

Comment: if it doesn't charge when off, then it's a BIOS issue. Try installing the newest BIOS.

Comment: So if you don't have access to windows and the proprietary tool made by intel for windows (and windows only of course), you have to find a manual way to update the bios / uefi. Be careful, find exactly what bios file do your computer needs, be aware of backup solution.

Comment: @Esther I've figured out how to update the BIOS and am now running the latest version, but it's still not charging.

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 I've snooped around a bit and found a setting to update the BIOS, but it's still not charging

Comment: An update; I discovered in the boot it now said no battery was present, so I unplugged everything, turned off the pc, removed the battery, pressed the power button for 15 seconds, put the battery back in and added the power cord. Now the battery is listed in the bios, but it still wont charge

Comment: Ive contacted HP and they told me a 7 year old pc shouldn't work anymore

Comment: @Nathan Not surprising that they said computer is obsolete! Do you have a multimeter? You should be sure that's your power cord and the battery is working.

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 I don't have a multimeter. I might try to borrow one but to be honest I've given up on this

Answer (score 0):

[My battery won't charge when plugged in (Ubuntu 18.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209033/my-battery-wont-charge-when-plugged-in-ubuntu-18-04)
I have resolved the issue after pressing the power button for nearly 30 seconds. I tried re-installing ubuntu 22.04, that also didnt help me. go through the ink.